# which is the standard way for writing html tag by php?

Tags: php, html

### which way is standard way to write html tags in php ?

i can write html codes directly . for example :

```
$output= "<body";
$output .= " class=\"some_class\"";
$output .=">"
```

or make some function for manipulating HTML tags and use them . for example :

```
function HTML_open_tag ($tagname){

    $GLOBALS['output'].=" <$tagname ";
}



function HTML_close_tag ($tagname=NULL){

    if ($tagname=="end"){
    $GLOBALS['output'].=" >";
    } elseif(isset($tagname)) {
    $GLOBALS['output'].=" </$tagname>";
    } else {
        $GLOBALS['output'].=" />";
    }
}


function HTML_tag_attribute ($attribute,$value){
    $GLOBALS['output'].=" $attribute=\"$value\"";
}
```

Comment: Neither are good - have a look at template engines such as Mustache. In general, avoid mixing logic and HTML and avoid global variables.

Comment: Pro-Templating Engine Comment: Use Twig, Smarty, Mustache. Anti-Templating Comment: PHP **is** a template engine already.

Comment: You probably want a templating engine. Smarty (http://www.smarty.net/) is probably the most established PHP option, although maybe not the best (Mustache as @Laurent mentions is a great option).

Comment: you could also use single quotes for the string, and double inside, eg $string = '<body class="name">'.

Comment: @Laurent why we should avoid global variables ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Heredoc `EOT`

```
echo <<< EOT
Your HTML here
EOT;
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I'm not clear on how this improves things for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of writing HTML tags using PHP. You can simply write your HTML in PHP using the [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) Syntax.

```
$output = <<<EOT

<p> my output </p>

EOT;
```

---

However if you want to avoid using tags, simply download and learn a framework which makes things a hell lot easier.

For example in [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), you can so easily write `br(4)` if you want to write 4 `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can do simple things like:

```
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';
```

This is as close as you can get to what you want without some SERIOUS custom coding.

It is designed for manipulating existing HTML - the big question really is:

**What are you trying to achieve????**

I am sure there are better ways to do what you are trying to do - let us know we might be able to point you in the right direction.

**EDIT**

The 'Standard' way to write html in PHP is to simply close your PHP tags before any html - re-open them when you need PHP magic to happen

```
<?php some junk like sessions etc.
?>
<html>
    <head>
         <title><?php echo $siteTitle; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
    <?php for($x=0;$x<3;$x++){?>
           <li id="listitem<?php echo $x;?>">ITEM: <?php echo $x;?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Does the above make sense?

Notice that I have a PHP loop - this will still function even though I have opened and closed PHP tags - it will 'print' or 'echo' whatever is in the middle of it.

Comment: it was interesting but i don't want to change existing HTML. i just want to write some HTML code.

Comment: i think it will limit me. what if some times we need <UL> and some times we don't ?

Comment: thats what if else statements are for - you can even (although performance wise I am not entirely sure if this has any major impact) use your if / else statement to just call seperate files with the code blocks you want in. - I was only showing that you can put loops etc. in - if you wanted you could put the whole <ul> inside an if statement.